# Xcode Swift Game ( Issue with Collisions )

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to get a "Block" to collide with the "ground" instead of the block going through the ground and disappearing!

Here is my code for the block

```
        hero = CSHero()
    hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)
    hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hero.size)
    hero.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    hero.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = heroCategory | groundCategory
    hero.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = heroCategory | groundCategory
    addChild(hero)
```

Here is my Code for the Ground

```
        let ground1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, 15))
    ground1.position = view.center
    ground1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground1.size)
    ground1.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground1.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory | heroCategory
    ground1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = groundCategory | heroCategory
    addChild(ground1)
```

Every time I run it the block just disappears if I have dynamic set to true.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting a very important part of physicsBody collision logic: `categoryBitMask`. The `categoryBitMask` property is what tells the system what type of object it is. You are essentially telling the system what you want each object to collide with but you are forgetting to tell the system what types of objects they actually are.

For further clarification, `contactTestBitMask` is needed only if you actually want to be notified when two things collide but don't want their physics bodies to act off of each other. (Think of when Mario hits a coin. He doesn't bounce off of it, but you need to be notified of said collision when you update the coin count). `collisionBitMask` tells the system what bodies to actually physically collide with. But this property needs to be paired with `categoryBitMask` to actually work.

Right now, you have everything you need. `Dynamic` isn't needed. What you need to do is add these two lines of code:

```
ground1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
hero.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = heroCategory
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That worked :) I'm having one issue though as he stays on the "ground" now, but he is all the way to the left of the screen! I can barely see him as 1/8th of his body is showing. I've tried to change the position of him but he just teleports back to the left of the screen when I do! Any suggestions?:)

Comment: This happens when Dynamic is set to true, but I need Dynamic to be set to true in order for the block to collide into other static blocks

Comment: Awesome! If it worked please accept the answer :) And if you want it to collide with other static blocks Then just update the collisionBitMask to the bit mask of the static blocks!

Comment: Without more code and further clarification as to what behavior you are trying to achieve, I can't really help.

Comment: Hector, are you there by chance?

Comment: I am so sorry! I'm here but I've been super busy on a project. What's up?